# Redux middleware being passed undefined actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've taken the Redux middleware from the [Isomorphic Redux App example here](https://github.com/caljrimmer/isomorphic-redux-app).

Looks like this:

```
export default function promiseMiddleware() {
  return next => action => {
    const { promise, type, ...rest } = action;

    if (!promise) return next(action);

    const REQUEST = type + '_REQUEST';
    const SUCCESS = type + '_SUCCESS';
    const FAILURE = type + '_FAILURE';

    next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST });

    return promise
      .then(res => {
        next({ ...rest, res, type: SUCCESS });
        return true;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE });
        return false;
      });
   };
}
```

The issue I'm having is that it's somehow being passed undefined actions, giving me a "Cannot get property `promise` of undefined" errors. I've checked the actions, reducers, etc... and all seem fine.

What could be causing this? Where would I even look?

Thanks.

Comment: try to change `return next => action =>` to  `return  store => next => action =>`